# Does Magento Cron Job reindex data now?

Tags: cron, reindex

Under Index Management, all categories were reindexed at the same time this morning. It was either someone did it, or the cron job did it.

But I confirmed that no one did it. I wonder if Magento cron job now reindex data. I know it didn't before, and I don't want any reindex in the cron job.

Here is my cron set up

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxx/public_html/cron.php -mdefault
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxx/public_html/cron.php -malways
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you didn't specify your Magento version, Magento 1.x series doesn't do it. It is surely, either triggered via admin or someone launched the command from shell.

If you happen to be in 2.x series(I highly doubt that, judging by the cron setup), cron is the only recommended way to re-index data now.